# Delete action to sql using swal

Tags: javascript, php, html

There's a form on one of my pages for which also I'm using Swal to ask the user to confirm his action (deleting a file) before making it happen.
Here's the Swal code:

```js
<script>
    function apagar(id) {
        
        swal({
            title: "Atenção",
            text: "Deseja eliminar o pedido com o id : " + id + " ?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            CancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: "Eliminar",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function () {
            swal("Pedido " + id + " eliminado com sucesso.", "Continuação de um bom trabalho.",
                "success");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'apagar.eventos.php',
                data: {
                    id: id

                },
                success: function (html) {
                     
                    window.location.href = 'index.php';
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

And this is my submit button:

```html
<button type="button"  id="<?php echo $idpedido;?>" onclick="apagar(this.id)" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar Agendamento</button>
```

And this is my delete code:

```js
<?php
include("db.connect.php");
$id2 = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM nagenda WHERE id = '$id2' ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

if you notice any hilarious mistake here, pardon my noobieness <

tried out all the suggestions that I found, like using the isConfirm function suggested by many users. But none worked.

**EDIT**

so i try on test files to see if i got error, so here is the code used on main file :

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="container col-md-5">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<?php $idpedido="1145";?>

<button type="button" id="<?php echo  $idpedido;?>" onclick="apagar(this.id)" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar Agendamento</button>

<script>
    function apagar(id) {
        
        swal({
            title: "Atenção",
            text: "delete id : " + id + " ?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            CancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: "yes",
            cancelButtonText: "no",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function () {
            swal("id " + id + " have been deleted.",
                "success");
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'teste2.php',
                data: {
                    id: id

                },
                success: function (html) {
                    include("teste2.php");
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
<script src="vendors/bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

code used to conect tu bd sql:

```html
<?php
$id2 = $_POST['id'];

include("agenda\dist\db.connect.php");
 
$sql = "DELETE FROM nagenda WHERE id = '$id2' ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

i'm geting error log :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at Object.doneFunction (texte.php:23)
at l (sweetalert.min.js:1)
at Object.s [as handleButton] (sweetalert.min.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.g (sweetalert.min.js:1)
```

Comment: You've not explained what isn't working?

Comment: @Script47 it just don't whant to delete

Comment: 1. Your PHP is open to SQL injection, use prepared statements. 2. Check the console response to see if the request is going through fine. 3. Check if the PHP is throwing error reporting (ensure error reporting is enabled).

Comment: @Script47  this code is a simple exemple of what i whant to do, is a test form.
I have check the console but i got no log on console from errors.
if i put print_r() don't show anytingh

Comment: @Script47 i just whant to simple have yes or no from user to delete row on sql, whit swal i'm trying to post the id to delete that id

Comment: help pls, i'm stuck on this one

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` implies that jQuery has not been loaded (correctly).

Comment: @Script47 that only happend when i click yes....

Comment: Irrespective of when it happened the error is still showing therefore my original comment still stands.

Comment: @Script47 can you still help solving?

Comment: if i put  "document.getElementById( ).onclick = function (){"
Who i indicate the id to delete?

Comment: @Script47 i changed my code, and i get no action, can you help me build one swal thet whorks better then what i'm trying to do? pls

Comment: No one has any idea how I can solve this, or how can I help you to understand better so that we can help each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i set the button id to "B1"
then i added the code:

```js
var clientId = document.getElementById('b1');

 clientId.onclick = function () {

  alertMessage(clientId.value);

 }

 function alertMessage(clientID) {
  swal({
   title: "Deseja eliminar o Agendamento?",
   text: "Se eliminar o agendamento não será possivel recuperar.",
   type: "warning",
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: "#f8b32d",
   confirmButtonText: "Eliminar",
   cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
   closeOnConfirm: false
  }, function () {
   swal("Agendamento liminado com sucesso.","success");
   sendAjax(clientID);
  });

  function sendAjax(clientID) {

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dist/apagar.eventos.php",
    data: {
     id: clientID
    },
    success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    window.location.reload()
    },
   });

  }

 }
```

looks like before i wasant indentified the button action..., worket for me